# Simple yet so hard: Jquery and scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

***Okay, so I am trying to do a couple of things:***

> 1. Create a list with an id and underlying
>
>    paragraphs
>
>    Assign text that is found in the DOM to each of the list paragraphs
>
>    Assign an id to some of the h2 paragraphs the DOM
>
>    use that id to automatically scroll down the page(yes i know this can be done in many different ways)

But, I ran into one problem which I have been stuck on for 3 hours now.
Whenever I do step nr. 3 my page automatically scrolls down it self. And yes I know it is possible to make the page scroll back up, but that is unnecessary code that I would like to avoid.

GIF: http://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-1640909552.gif

Here is my code

**JS**

```
    window.onload = function () {

        $("<ul id='list'> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> </ul>").insertAfter(".content h1");

        for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            $("#list li:nth-child("+i+")").html("<a>" + $(".content h2:nth-of-type(" +i+ ")").text() + "</a>");
            $(".content h2:nth-of-type("+i+")").attr("id", "h2nr"+i); //this little sh#t makes my page scroll down >:(
            $("#list li:nth-of-type("+i+") a").attr("href", "#h2nr"+i);
            }
}; //end of ONLOAD
```

**HTML**

> This page is only made for training and is not intended for any
>   commercial use and may therefor have a couple of faults;

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Specials | The Landon Hotel</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="challenge.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header"><img src="img/header.png"></div>
        <div id="hero">
            <div class="current"><img src="img/HomePageImages/Paris.jpg"></div>
        </div>

<nav class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
<div>
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav-menu">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="restaurant-to-room-service.html">Room Service</a></li>
<li><a href="specials.html">Specials</a></li>
<li><a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a></li>
<li><a href="meetings-events.html">Meetings &#038; Events</a></li>
<li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div>
</nav>

        <div class="content">   
        <h1>Specials</h1>   
        <h2>San Francisco, Bernal Heights</h2>
        <h3>Military Family Deal:</h3>
        <p>Active and retired military, and their families, save 20% when booking a three or more day stay at the Landon Hotel in lovely Bernal Heights, San Francisco. Book by August 1st, 2015.</p> 
        <h3>Bring Fido:</h3>
        <p>Bring your travel-loving canine to our pet-friendly Bernal Heights Landon Hotel, and see why San Francisco is a dog's paradise, with endless activities and locations that cater to canines. You'll save 10% just for bringing Fido, and there are no hidden pet fees. Book by April 30th, 2014.</p> 
        <h3>Meeting Mondays:</h3>
        <p>The new Bernal Heights conference room is just the place for your corporate meetings, and if you book for three or more consecutive days, that include a Monday, you'll receive Monday free. Book by September 15th, 2014.</p>
<hr/>
        <h2>London, West End</h2>
        <h3>Theatre Package:</h3>
        <p>Theatre lovers can enjoy two free tickets to a West End theater production of their choice, when booking a weekend stay at the West End Landon.  Tickets are mezzanine level and are limited to available productions at the time of booking. Book by August 1st, 2015.</p>
        <h3>Shopper's Paradise:</h3>
        <p>Oxford, Regent, and Bond Streets have some of the best shopping in the world, and all are just a tube stop away when you stay at the West End Landon. And, if you book a minimum of five days, you'll get a bonus gift certificate worth $125 to use in the boutique of your choice, based on participating vendors at time of booking. Book by November 2015.</p>
<hr/>       
        <h2>Hong Kong, Kwun Tong</h2>
        <h3>Spa Holiday:</h3>
        <p>The Hong Kong is home to a half-dozen world-renowned spas, some tucked away in skyscrapers, others in beachside retreats. You can have your pick of a one-day Spa Holiday if you book a five-consecutive night stay during the months of February through April. Book by November 1, 2014.</p>
        <h3>Leisure and Luxury:</h3>
        <p>Stay at the Landon Hotel in the Kwun Tong District and you'll have both leisure and luxury at your fingertips. Play a complimentary round of golf and enjoy a complimentary seaweed body wrap and massage, if you book a weekend stay by August 1st , 2015.</p> 
<hr/>
        <h2>Paris, Latin Quarter</h2>
        <h3>Sweet Deal:</h3>
        <p>Paris is renowned for its delectable pastries and other dessert creations by the most highly skilled chefs in the world. If you book a weekend stay by February 28th, 2015 you'll receive a complimentary dessert tray every night of your stay. Be prepared for a sweet feast!</p>
        <h3>Spiritual Walk:</h3>
        <p>The Latin Quarter is the place to tour some of the world's oldest churches and monasteries. You can enjoy a complimentary church walking tour for two, guided by an entertaining and enlightening guide, if you book a weekend stay by March 1, 2015.</p>
        <h3>Holiday Package:</h3>
        <p>Spend the winter holidays in Paris and enjoy festivity and fine food under a star-filled winter sky. You'll receive 15% off your hotel accommodations, if you reserve for 7 consecutive nights in December 2014 or January 2015.  Book by October 30th, 2014.</p>
<hr/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This sounds to me like a css issue as well. Can you throw all of this in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @J4G I have never used it before but I have seen some examples of it so it may not be perfect. NOTE: some of the pics are missing

https://jsfiddle.net/StanlyHV/mvfbuo1z/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the Javascript to do what you wanted.  I used the each function so it automatically selects all the H2 elements and builds the list afterwards to do the scrolling.  You can also use jquery's scroll plugin to make it a smooth scroll.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var items = $('.content h2');
    var list = $('<ul id="list"></ul>');
    items.each(function(i, el) {
      var e = $(el);
      var a = $('<a name="h2nr' + i + '"></a>'),
        listA = $('<a href="#h2nr' + i + '">' + e.html() + '</a>');
      e.append(a);
      var li = $('<li></li>');
      li.append(listA);
      list.append(li);
    });

    list.insertBefore('.content');

    var loc = location.href;
    if (loc.indexOf('#') > -1) {
      loc = loc.substring(0, loc.indexOf('#'));
      }
    loc+="#";//Scroll to top...
     location.href = loc;
      
    }; //end of ONLOAD
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Specials | The Landon Hotel</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="challenge.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <img src="img/header.png">
    </div>
    <div id="hero">
      <div class="current">
        <img src="img/HomePageImages/Paris.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
      <div>
        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav-menu">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="restaurant-to-room-service.html">Room Service</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="specials.html">Specials</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="meetings-events.html">Meetings &#038; Events</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="news.html">News</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="content">
      <h1>Specials</h1> 
      <h2>San Francisco, Bernal Heights</h2>
      <h3>Military Family Deal:</h3>
      <p>Active and retired military, and their families, save 20% when booking a three or more day stay at the Landon Hotel in lovely Bernal Heights, San Francisco. Book by August 1st, 2015.</p>
      <h3>Bring Fido:</h3>
      <p>Bring your travel-loving canine to our pet-friendly Bernal Heights Landon Hotel, and see why San Francisco is a dog's paradise, with endless activities and locations that cater to canines. You'll save 10% just for bringing Fido, and there are no
        hidden pet fees. Book by April 30th, 2014.</p>
      <h3>Meeting Mondays:</h3>
      <p>The new Bernal Heights conference room is just the place for your corporate meetings, and if you book for three or more consecutive days, that include a Monday, you'll receive Monday free. Book by September 15th, 2014.</p>
      <hr/>
      <h2>London, West End</h2>
      <h3>Theatre Package:</h3>
      <p>Theatre lovers can enjoy two free tickets to a West End theater production of their choice, when booking a weekend stay at the West End Landon. Tickets are mezzanine level and are limited to available productions at the time of booking. Book by
        August 1st, 2015.</p>
      <h3>Shopper's Paradise:</h3>
      <p>Oxford, Regent, and Bond Streets have some of the best shopping in the world, and all are just a tube stop away when you stay at the West End Landon. And, if you book a minimum of five days, you'll get a bonus gift certificate worth $125 to use
        in the boutique of your choice, based on participating vendors at time of booking. Book by November 2015.</p>
      <hr/>
      <h2>Hong Kong, Kwun Tong</h2>
      <h3>Spa Holiday:</h3>
      <p>The Hong Kong is home to a half-dozen world-renowned spas, some tucked away in skyscrapers, others in beachside retreats. You can have your pick of a one-day Spa Holiday if you book a five-consecutive night stay during the months of February through
        April. Book by November 1, 2014.</p>
      <h3>Leisure and Luxury:</h3>
      <p>Stay at the Landon Hotel in the Kwun Tong District and you'll have both leisure and luxury at your fingertips. Play a complimentary round of golf and enjoy a complimentary seaweed body wrap and massage, if you book a weekend stay by August 1st ,
        2015.
      </p>
      <hr/>
      <h2>Paris, Latin Quarter</h2>
      <h3>Sweet Deal:</h3>
      <p>Paris is renowned for its delectable pastries and other dessert creations by the most highly skilled chefs in the world. If you book a weekend stay by February 28th, 2015 you'll receive a complimentary dessert tray every night of your stay. Be prepared
        for a sweet feast!</p>
      <h3>Spiritual Walk:</h3>
      <p>The Latin Quarter is the place to tour some of the world's oldest churches and monasteries. You can enjoy a complimentary church walking tour for two, guided by an entertaining and enlightening guide, if you book a weekend stay by March 1, 2015.</p>
      <h3>Holiday Package:</h3>
      <p>Spend the winter holidays in Paris and enjoy festivity and fine food under a star-filled winter sky. You'll receive 15% off your hotel accommodations, if you reserve for 7 consecutive nights in December 2014 or January 2015. Book by October 30th,
        2014.
      </p>
      <hr/>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks dor the input, but when I tried your code it automatically scrolled itself down to the bottom of the page, also the list was placed at the bottom. **(Did not try the html as I assume it is the same as the one I already have)**

Comment: You confused me then :)  You want the list at the top? Thats easy, what do you mean that it automatically scrolled to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Yep! sorry if i confused you. My goal is to have the html and possibly js as is except it scrolling down to h2nr3 by itself whenever the page loads

Comment: I think you mean the way it autoscrolls if you already had #h2nr3 in the url? That is a browser feature, but you may be able to remove it after the fact...

Comment: I think the changes I made should fix your issue.

Comment: you're right! its probably because of the url! Thanks for the help! not that it is a problem any more, but how would you suggest to remove #h2nr3 from the url after you clicked the link?

Comment: I added the changes to the code in the snippet.  I just remove the #h2nr3  and replace it with # So it just goes to the top

Comment: That seems to do the trick! again thank you for your help! it is greatly appreciated!